# Populate form with data from relation table

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to populate a form with relational data. For example if i do

```
form = CreateCompany(obj=company)
```

this will only populate the form with data directly from the main table, not from the relations table.

```
class Company(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'companies_company'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    industry_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('industries.id'))

class Industry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'industries'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    industry = db.Column(db.String(100))
    company_industry = db.relationship('Company', backref='company_industry', lazy='joined')
```

form

```
class CreateCompany(Form):
    company_name = StringField('Company name', [Required()])
    industry = SelectField('Industry')
    industry_id = HiddenField('Industry_id')
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: How do `Company` and `Industry` relate?

Comment: A company can have only one industry, and one industry could be used by multiple companies. Basically a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: Your models don't reflect that. Did you share the full models or only a limited number of fields?

Comment: @dirn only a limited number of fields. But i am looking only for a generic example, you can ignore my code if you want. thanks

Comment: Do you have a foreign key field from `Country` to `Industry`? If not, that's your problem. If you do, and you just didn't include it in your example, your problem is something else entirely.

Comment: @dirn please see the updated code. Its exactly what i have. thanks

Comment: @dirn can you see my answer. that solves my problem, but i am not sure, if is the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I need to create a relation between Company and industry.

Something like this in model: `industry_rel = db.relationship('Industry', backref='company')`

Then, I can do this in the form constructor of `CreateCompany`.

```
 def __init__(self, default, *args, **kwargs):
     self.industry.kwargs['default'] = default #default is company.industry_rel.id
```

---

```
 form = CreateCompany(company.industry_rel.id, obj=company)
```

In this case, I am only populating manually what I can't do automatically with  `obj=company`